# How to move a date conversion to the end of the end of the Quarter?

Tags: matlab, date, datetime

I'm trying to convert a date in matlab to the end of the quarter after getting data in the quarterly format.

For a date in the format Year-Quarter

```
>> date1='2014Q1';
>> datetime(date1,'InputFormat','yyyyQQ','Format','MM/dd/yyyy')

ans =

    01/01/2014
```

I would like to make this output 3/31/2014 as that would be the date at the end of the quarter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a `datetime` object for the second quarter of the year, then go back one day in time by subtracting one day from the beginning of the second quarter so you get the end of the first quarter.  In that case, your date should become `'2014Q2'` to denote the second quarter of the year.

```
>> date1 = '2014Q2'; %// Change - note Q2, not Q1
>> datetime(date1,'InputFormat','yyyyQQ','Format','MM/dd/yyyy') - days(1)

ans = 

   03/31/2014
```

The function [`days`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/days.html) gives you a `datetime`object that's the equivalent of 1 day, and so subtracting this from your `datetime` object that starts in the second quarter will give you the end of the first quarter.